# Is there a cyclic group $|\langle hk\rangle|= L$ or $|\langle hk\rangle|\ne L$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

$G$ is Abelian, $H=\langle h\rangle$ and  $K=\langle k\rangle$ are distinct cyclic subgroups of $G$, $|H|=r, |K|=s$, let $L$ be the least common multiple of $r$ and $s$. I am wondering if $\langle hk\rangle$ is a cyclic subgroup with order $|\langle hk\rangle|=L$, or if this idea is incorrect then what is the counter-example?

Here is my attempt:

Let $r=r_1\sigma, s=s_1\sigma$, where $\sigma\in \mathbb{N}$, and $r_1, s_1$ are coprimes, hence $L=r_1\sigma s_1$. Since $G$ is Abelian, it is easy to check $(hk)^L=e$. Now assume $|\langle hk\rangle|=q, q\le L$, so we have $(hk)^q=e\Rightarrow h^q=k^{-q}$, define $x=h^q=k^{-q}$, and let $u=|\langle x\rangle|$, which gives $x^u=e$.

Since $\langle x\rangle\le H\Rightarrow u|r\Rightarrow u|r_1\sigma$, similarly, since $\langle x\rangle\le K\Rightarrow u|s\Rightarrow u|s_1\sigma$.
Therefore, we get $u|\sigma\Rightarrow \sigma=tu,  x^\sigma=(x^u)^t=e$ and we have

$x^u=h^{qu}=e\Rightarrow r|qu\Rightarrow r_1\sigma|qu\Rightarrow r_1tu|qu\Rightarrow r_1t|q$

$x^u=k^{qu}=e\Rightarrow s|qu\Rightarrow s_1\sigma|qu\Rightarrow s_1tu|
qu\Rightarrow s_1t|q$

Since $r_1, s_1$ are coprimes, we have $r_1ts_1|q$.

Let $q=\alpha\cdot r_1 t s_1$ and write $L=r_1\sigma s_1=u\cdot r_1t s_1$, so we get

$$\Rightarrow 1\le\alpha\le u$$

Since $q|L$, we have

$$\alpha|u$$

I stuck here, it didn't give any contradictions, can I get some hint to proceed? or a counter-example to show $|\langle hk\rangle|< L$?

Comment: $|\langle hk\rangle\mid L$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4496514/11619). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2119114/11619) the idea  is similar, but the assumption that the two subgroups be distinct was missing. My answer is an adaptation of that.

Comment: In your proof I don’t understand/can’t fill details of following statement: (1) Let $r=r_1\sigma, s=s_1\sigma$, where $\sigma\in \mathbb{N}$, and $r_1, s_1$ are coprimes. (2) $\langle x\rangle \leq G\Rightarrow u\mid r_1\sigma \Rightarrow u\mid \sigma$. (3) Since $r_1, s_1$ are coprimes, we have $r_1ts_1|q$. By the way $|u|=\frac{r}{(q,r)}=\frac{s}{(q,s)}$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the group $\Bbb{Z}_2\times \Bbb{Z}_4$ and $H=\langle (0,1)\rangle $
and $K=\langle (1,1)\rangle $

$|H|=|K|=4$

$|\langle (0,1)+(1,1)\rangle |=|\langle (1,2)\rangle|=2 $

Answer (score 2):

The order can be smaller.

Consider the following subgroups of $\Bbb{Z}_{30}$. The element $h=\overline{4}$ generates the unique subgroup of order $15$. The element $k=\overline{21}$ generates the unique subgroup of order $10$. The element $h+k=\overline{25}$ generates a subgroup of order $6$ only.

The problem is that in the projection to the quotient group $\Bbb{Z}_5\simeq \Bbb{Z}_{30}/\langle\overline{5}\rangle$ the images of $h$ and $k$ become each others inverses. If we pick generators more carefully this won't happen. For example $\overline{2}$ generates the same subgroup as $\overline{4}$, and $\overline{2}+\overline{21}=\overline{23}$ does generate a subgroup of order $\mathrm{lcm}(15,10)=30$.

Comment: This should be a duplicate, but I could not find one right away. Will delete, when a good target is located.

Comment: I don't get "the image of h and k become each others inverse". $\langle h \rangle=\langle 2 \rangle$, $\langle k \rangle=\langle 3 \rangle$. The quotient group $\{ \langle 5 \rangle, 1+\langle 5 \rangle, 2+\langle 5 \rangle, 3+\langle 5 \rangle, 4+\langle 5 \rangle\}$, so each element in the quotient group contains three elements from $\langle h \rangle$, two elements from $\langle k \rangle$. But I don't understand how is this related to "the image of h and k become each others inverse"?

Comment: @MathFail: It isn't. The image of $h$ is $4+\langle 5\rangle$, and image of $k$ is $1+\langle 5\rangle$, and they are inverses of each other in the quotient.

Comment: @MathFail: The map is the canonical map from $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_5$. Wbhat is the problem? $a+\langle 30\rangle$ maps to $a+\langle 5\rangle$.

Comment: Ok, so it is by default the canonical map. Yes, then the image of h and image of k are the inverse of each other. But how does this help to explain the OP? Later on he picked the generator $h=\bar{2}$ instead of $h=\bar{4}$, in this case, $2+\langle 5\rangle$ is not an inverse of $21+\langle 5\rangle$, and this way works as desired. So it seems as long as the images are not the inverse of each other, then the OP holds, but why? I can't see the connection between the quotient group and the OP. @ArturoMagidin